# Why cant I follow using twitter api free version?

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, twitterapi-python, twitter-follow, twitter-api-v1

According to https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1 , twitter follow is allowed on the free version.

This my code :
`def follow_user(api, username): try: api.create_friendship(screen_name=username)   print(f'Successfully followed {username}.') except tweepy.errors.TweepyException as e : print(f'Error: {e}')`

Error message :
Error: 403 Forbidden
453 - You currently have access to a subset of Twitter API v2 endpoints and limited v1.1 endpoints (e.g. media post, oauth) only. If you need access to this endpoint, you may need a different access level. You can learn more here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/product

How can I fix this ? Please help. Thank you!

Was expecting the api will be used to follow the username.